# Create color vector list according to order in a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe  such as :

```
COL1 COL2
VAL1 ok
VAL1 ok
VAL2 ok
VAL3 ok
VAL3 ok
VAL4 ok
VAL1 ok
```

and a vector such as :

```
my_vector<-c("VAL1"="red","VAL2"="blue","VAL3"="green","VAL4"="yellow")
```

How could I create a vector color such as :

```
my_vector_color<- c("red","red","blue","green","green","yellow","red")
```

which follow the order of the table ?

thanks a lot for your help

Comment: `unname(my_vector[df$COL1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below

```
> transform(
+   df,
+   COL1 = my_vector[COL1]
+ )
    COL1 COL2
1    red   ok
2    red   ok
3   blue   ok
4  green   ok
5  green   ok
6 yellow   ok
7    red   ok
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with join

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[stack(my_vector), COL1 := values, on = .(COL1 = ind)]
```

-output

```
> df1
     COL1 COL2
1:    red   ok
2:    red   ok
3:   blue   ok
4:  green   ok
5:  green   ok
6: yellow   ok
7:    red   ok
```